# Supercapacitors as EV batteries

Tags: supercapacitor

How can we make a supercapacitor bank of 48 V, 8000 F disharge slower when operating an EV motor having following specification:

1. Voltage: 48
2. Power: 15 kw
3. Type: BLDC/3 ph AC induction
4. Efficiency: upto 93%

I wish to use this motor to run an electric car for 120 - 200 km per charge. Please note that my EV will be designed for a max speed of 120 kmph.

Comment: You can't. Discharge is proportional to energy taken out. Slower discharge with the same energy out is against the law of conversation of energy.

Comment: Should be conservation not conversation!

Comment: Batteries maintain fairly constant voltage through their discharge cycle until the energy is used up and the voltage starts to fall. Capacitors - super or otherwise - will suffer voltage drop from the very beginning.

Comment: Use less power. That means, make it lighter or slower. But there is still no way your wish of 120km range will be granted.

Answer (score 2):

Capacitors are quite efficient at storing then releasing energy.  A particular capacitor can only hold some maximum energy.  To drain it longer, you have to drain it at lower power, meaning less energy per unit time.

If you have a 100 gallon tank of water, and remove water at the rate of 1 gallon per minute, then the tank will be empty in 100 minutes.  The same basic logic works with capacitors, or anything else that stores something.

You claim to have a 8000 F capacitor that can be charged to 48 V.  The total energy it can store is:

E = ½ C V<sup>2</sup>

½ (8000 F)(48 V)<sup>2</sup> = 9.22 MJ

If you drain your tank of 9.22 MJ at 15 kJ per second, it will run out in 614 seconds, or about 10 minutes.  Since the circuit needs some minimum voltage to function, all the energy in the cap can't be used, so the actual run time will be less than indicated by the total energy in the cap.  Put another way, when the cap gets low, you can no longer take out energy.  Some energy will remain in the cap.

So to answer your question of how to make 9.22 MJ last longer when drawing from it at a rate of 15 kW, the answer is *you can't*.  To make it last longer, you either have to increase the amount of stored energy, or draw it at a lower rate.

The obvious solution is to use batteries instead of capacitors.  With current technology, they have a much larger energy density in terms of weight, size, and cost.

Comment: What capacity will be good?

Comment: Can you suggest me a way other than increasing the time constant of the capacitor bank to let it drain out at a rate comparable to the discharge rate of a lead acid and a lithium ion battery pack for an EV?

Comment: @Anub: You can't cheat around the laws of physics.  Read what I wrote and actually try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to study the subject first, BEFORE you commit yourself to ANY performance standards. In this case, you've gotten yourself into all sorts of trouble.

The very first thing you should have done was researched the energy efficiency of automobiles. Try [here, for instance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_per_gallon_gasoline_equivalent) If you read it and pay attention, you'll see that a reasonable number for an electric car (small and light) is on the order of 5 mi/kwH, or about 8 km/kWh. Note that this is almost certainly not at speeds of 120 km/hr.

Since a kWh is 1 kw x 3600 sec, that's an energy efficiency of about .45 MJ/km. Add in a factor of 1/0.93 for motor efficiency, and in round numbers you need .5 MJ/km.

To look at it another way, you motor is spec'ed for 15 kW. In one hour it will require 15 kWh total energy. For the efficiency stated, that will be 8 km/kWh x 15 kW, for a maximum speed of 120 km/hr. So the motor is actually properly sized for a vehicle such as an EV-1. Except that the EV-1 performance given in the link may well have happened at a lower average speed. If so, you won't get even 120.

Now. How big is your battery/supercap? Since $$E = \frac{CV^2}{2}$$ let's assume that, in order to run at full speed the battery/supercap needs a voltage of no less than 90% of maximum, and the total energy available is $$E=\frac{8000*48^2(1^2-.9^2)}{2}$$ or 1.75 MJ.

Do you see a problem? I do hope so.

Your supercap will provide enough energy to drive about 3 km or so.

Of course, if you're using a very small, very light vehicle you'll do much better than this, but I'd be astonished if you got a factor of 10 better. You don't talk about how you're going to make this vehicle, and perhaps it's going to be super-optimized for low drag and 1 driver only. If so, you may stand a chance, but it won't remotely be a practical vehicle.

As for your original question, it's been answered - you can't. Or rather, if you hope to put out the rated power, well, power is power. If you can make a really low-drag vehicle which uses less than the maximum motor power to achieve the speeds you want, then you'll draw less power than specified.

Lots of luck. You're going to need it.